# Setting a Timeout on an AudioInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, audio, timeout, inputstream

I am playing audio received through an `AudioInputStream`. The audio data is stored on a remote server.

Retrieving the `AudioInputStream` via `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(path))` works perfectly, however I require a `timeout` on this `InputStream`.

I thought I might be able to create a `Socket` connection to the `URL` and then utilise the `Socket` timeout, however AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream) requires the InputStream to be mark supported. This is when I wrapped the `Socket` `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` and received the following error message:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getFMT(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Working code:

```
audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(path));
```

Code that causes `EOFException`:

```
audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Why is the `EOFException` occurring, and is it possible to add a timeout to an `AudioInputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing the `Socket` with a `URLConnection`, I was able to resolve the issue. I'm assuming this is because the `Socket` connection (at least in the manner I set it up) opened an input stream to the actual server (server.com) rather than a file on the server as I intended.